# Msfvenom format specifier

Tags: payload, metasploit

In msfvenom what does it mean exactly when i specify the format to C or Python? And what is the format 'raw' for? I know, when the format is psh-cmd it runs in the command prompt and when it is exe it runs as a normal executable, what about the others?

```
msfvenom -p windows/shell/reverse_tcp -f c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C and python are other programming languages.

psh_cmd is a powershell (programming language)

and exe is simply a compiled executable.